# How to take an array index list if condition in programming for android?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I make use of an array list imageView shuffle, how to take an array index value in the input list into the if condition? Sample code as below but what is the solution if conditions do not want to walk?

This is the code : if (soal.equals(list.get(0)) && text.getText().toString().equals("one") )

```
public class tebakgambar extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button ok;
    private ImageView soal;
    private EditText text;

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
        add(R.drawable.siji);
        add(R.drawable.loro);
        add(R.drawable.telu);
        add(R.drawable.papat);
        add(R.drawable.limo);
        add(R.drawable.enem);
        add(R.drawable.pitu);
        add(R.drawable.wolu);
        add(R.drawable.songo);
        add(R.drawable.nol);
    }};



    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.soal);


        soal = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        ok.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        acak();
       jawaban();

    }

    private void acak(){

        Collections.shuffle(list);
        soal.setImageResource(list.get(0));
        soal.setTag(list.get(0));

    }

    private void jawaban() {

        if (soal.equals(list.get(0)) && text.getText().toString().equals("one") ) {
            text.setText("");
            // get your custom_toast.xml ayout
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout_id));

            // set a dummy image
            ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.benar);

            // set a message
            // TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
            //text.setText("Benar");

            // Toast...
            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.show();
        } else {
            text.setText("");
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout_id));

            // set a dummy image
            ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.salah);

            // set a message
            // TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
            //text.setText("Benar");

            // Toast...
            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly,

```
soal.equals(list.get(0))
```

is wrong. "soal" is an ImageView object and you are equating it with an Integer (as the ArrayList is of Integer type). This is not correct in any way.

You need to do this,

```
soal.getId().equals(list.get(0))
```

I don't know the rest of your code logic, but this should work.

Comment: Is your problem resolved? Or you need any more help on it?